# Serialize <form> data in React JS to submit POST request

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, serialization, reactjs

I have a very basic comment form that takes some text input from a user and sends a `POST` request via AJAX to create a new comment.

```
var CommentForm = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    // ...
    // ...
  },

  handleFormSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var component = this;

    return $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: this.props.someURL,
      data: // ???? - Need to figure out how to serialize data here,
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json",
      success: (function(response){ alert("SUCESS") }),
      error: (function(){ alert("ERROR"); })
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    var component = this;

    return (
      <form onSubmit={component.handleFormSubmit} className="comments__form" id="new_comment" accept-charset="UTF-8">
        // ...
      </form>
    );
  }
});
```

I need to serialize the form data to send along with my `POST` request, but I'm not sure how. I know in JQuery I can select the form element and do something like `$("#my_form").serialize()`, but I can't seem to call that from inside the React component (not sure why?)

Some other stackoverflow answers suggested adding a `ref='foo'` to each relevant DOM element and then I can access them with `React.findDOMNode(this.refs.foo).getValue();`. This works fine but it leaves me to manually construct the whole serialized form data string, which isn't pretty if the form is a lot longer and complex.

```
// Sample serialized form string
"utf8=✓&authenticity_token=+Bm8bJT+UBX6Hyr+f0Cqec65CR7qj6UEhHrl1gj0lJfhc85nuu+j2YhJC8f4PM1UAJbhzC0TtQTuceXpn5lSOg==&comment[body]=new+comment!"
```

Is there a more idiomatic way to approach this - perhaps a helper that will let me serialize my form data within ReactJS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would usually use the component `state` to store all the information.

For example, when an inputs text is changed, you would change the state to reflect that:

`<input type="text" onChange={ (e) => this.setState({ text: e.target.value }) }`

Then, when it comes to submit the form you can access the value using `this.state.text`.

This does mean that you would have to build the object yourself however, although, this could be achieved via a loop:

```
this.state.map((value, index) => {
  obj[index] = value;
});
```

and then send `obj` as the post data.

**UPDATE**

The only performance issue with updating the state is that the component is re-rendered each time. This isn't an issue and is the way react components work, as long as you watch for the size of the render method and what it is doing.

Forms in the usual HTML `<form>` tag sense, don't exist within React. You use the form components to change the state. I suggest reading up on [React Forms](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html)

In terms of the UTF8 flag, that would be the value of a hidden field, so you could use `refs` in this case to get that value for your object:

`<input type="text" ref="utf8" value="✓" />`

`obj.utf8 = this.refs['utf8'].value`

Comment: Interesting, thanks! A few clarifications - isn't it a costly operation to update the `state` of my text on every change? If the user is tying out several hundred characters, that's several hundred state changes. Secondly, this approach seems to completely bypass traditional HTML forms - we're no longer using the submit functionality so `method='post'` and similar attributes have no meaning in the html form. And the serialized data is manually constructed so it may or may not conform to a standard (e.g. including `utf` flag). Is this just sorted of accepted as ok to do within the React world?

Comment: This answer reads as though `this.state` is an array, but it's a plain object and there is no native `map()` function for objects.

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to use `Serialize` form in `ReactJs` with functional component try this:

## **1. Create a state**

```
const [form, setForm] = useState({});
```

## **2. Create a function handler**

```
const handleForm = (name, value) => {
     setForm({...form, [name]: value});
}
```

Now you got your object here:

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
     console.log(form);
}
```

## **3. In your render**

```
<form>
     <input onChange={(e)=>handleForm('name', e.target.value)} />
     <input onChange={(e)=>handleForm('phone', e.target.value)} />
     <button onClick={()=>handleSubmit()}>Submit</button>
</form>
```

## **UPDATE 2022**

Or use **[useForm](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/)**

*useForm is a custom hook for managing forms with ease. It takes one object as optional argument. The following example demonstrates all of its properties along with their default values.*